# Discretization of test dataset

Tags: java, weka

I'm using Weka's API to classify some data. I use the BayesNet algorithm and therefore need to discretize the numeric values in the dataset. I have read that I need to use the training dataset as input format when discretizing the test dataset, so that the discretized training and test datasets are compatible (https://weka.wikispaces.com/Discretizing+datasets). I have used the filter:

```
weka.filters.supervised.attribute.Discretize.
```

This is my code for discretization of the test dataset:

```
private Instances filterData(Instances testData) {      
    int[] discIndices = {0,2,5,6}; //indices of numeric attributes

    Discretize discFilter = new Discretize();       

    try {           
        discFilter.setAttributeIndicesArray(discIndices);
        discFilter.setInputFormat(trainingData); // notice that the traning data is used as input format

        return Filter.useFilter(testData, discFilter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I use the same arff file for training and testing everything works fine. But of course I want to use test data that is from a different (test) arff file (sometimes with only one instance).The problem is that when I use a different test arff file the dicretization doesn't work any more. For example, I have one numeric attribute that gets 6 intervals when I discretize the training data and it only gets 1 interval when I discretize the test data, which of course make the training and test data incompatible. Does anyone know why this happens? I really thought that when I use the training data as input format to the discretization filter when discretizing the test data, the filter would create the same intervals as when discretizing the training data.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that one should discretize a single test instance by using this code:

```
discFilter.input(instance);
Instance filteredInstance = discFilter.output();
```